# Strange Characters in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8.1, start-menu, special-characters

A PC of a friend of mine just start to showing this strange characters and I don't know what to do. It's just like this:

[image]

He can't do anything because from time to time (like seconds) the start menu appears again . Does anybody know what is this?

It should be noted that he tried to plugin an external disc and his antivirus notified him that the device would be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font has been set to Windings. Go into the settings and change the font to something else.

Comment: I would do that if i could just get out of the star menu wich i can't due to it's "reboot" (start menu  starts to appear and desappear).

Comment: Hmm, if you cannot do anything with the phone, resetting to factory defaults might be the only way. There's a keycombination while powering on to do this. I believe volume up + power on to initiate a factory default routine.